# How to created 3d array in python3 from split of text linux command?

Tags: arrays, linux, python-3.x, python-3.5

Good morning,

Dear all,

How to create 3 dimensional array in python3 from split on string command?
Here is how I did it with creating 3 one dimensional arrays.

```
fs_usage=subprocess.check_output(["df -k | awk '{print $3 \",\" $4 \",\" $6}'  | awk '{if(NR>0)print}'"],shell=True,universal_newlines=True)
data_arr=fs_usage.split()
arr_used=[]
arr_available=[]
arr_mounted=[]
for i in data_arr:
    used,available,munted=i.split(",")
    arr_used.append(used)
    arr_available.append(available)
    arr_mounted.append(munted)
    # print(i)
print(arr_used,arr_available,arr_mounted)
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example of the output you'd like? I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sure please see it below:

Comment: ['9260312', '35676', '89803096', '177592', '4296', '7261132', '546774132', '266992460', '1976228', '69793452', '1074308280', '390595824', '72'] ['868708', '8109852', '103049352', '3389364', '2653744', '1261144', '3568272', '26768564', '27267160', '18630128', '29306348', '14161384', '1629036'] ['/', '/tmp', '/test', '/boot', '/home', '/var', '/mnt/install', '/mnt/snapshot', '/mnt/share', '/mnt/storage', '/mnt/linux', '/mnt/download', '/run/user/1001']

Comment: Could you just do something like `my_array = [arr_used, arr_available, arr_mounted]`?

Comment: I try this but is just adding on record here is output

Comment: ['72', '1629036', '/run/user/1001']

Comment: code info_arr=[used,available,munted]

Answer (score 0):

You can see solution below

```
info_arr=[[]]
info_arr.pop()
# print(data_arr)
for i in data_arr:
    info_arr.append(i.split(","))
```